# ordering a list python list of objects

Tags: python

I have a list containing `Student` objects with the following attributes: `name`, `hours` and `qpoints`.  The list is stored in the variable `data`.  Why am I getting a `None` return in the following? In other words, `data.sort(key = Student.gpa)` returns `None`, even though there is a method returning the gpa in the `Student` class.  I have imported the `Student` class in my code.

```
def choiceInput(data):
    choice = input('Enter method of sorting <GPA>, <Name>, or <Credits>: ')
    choice = choice[0].lower()
    if choice == 'g':
        return data.sort(key = Student.gpa)
    elif choice == 'n':
        return data.sort(key = Student.getName)
    else:
        return data.sort(key = Student.getpPoints)
```

Answer (score 1):

`sort` sorts a list in-place and returns `None`. If you print `data` after calling `sort` you'll find it sorted as you expected.